# ssh is using wrong key despite config and bypassing config

Tags: git, ssh

When I try to connect to github using `ssh` I get the following:

```sh
me@host ~/repos/my_repo (main) $ git pull
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '140.82.114.4' to the list of known hosts.
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

The [github docs](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/error-permission-denied-publickey) suggest running the following command to debug the `ssh` connection, which gives me the following output. Note that the github key is in `~/.ssh/github_id_rsa`, but it never seems to attempt to use that key, even though my config lists it specifically as the key to use for this host:

```sh
$ ssh -vT git@github.com
OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/me/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/me/.ssh/config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 47: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to github.com port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/me/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /Users/me/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version babeld-74336b10
debug1: no match: babeld-74336b10
debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: rsa-sha2-512
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/me/.ssh/known_hosts:10
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '140.82.112.4' to the list of known hosts.
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/me/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:lKbkgpDG6HpW4U1pB8nQDxkAj1M4asDmdQclOe4FEJY explicit agent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/me/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:lKbkgpDG6HpW4U1pB8nQDxkAj1M4asDmdQclOe4FEJY explicit agent
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

I added `-F /dev/null` to bypass my config file to see if it was a problem with my config):

```sh
$ ssh -vT git@github.com -F /dev/null
OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /dev/null
debug1: Connecting to github.com port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/me/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /Users/me/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/me/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/me/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/me/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/me/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/me/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/me/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/me/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/me/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version babeld-74336b10
debug1: no match: babeld-74336b10
debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: rsa-sha2-512
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/me/.ssh/known_hosts:10
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/me/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:lKbkgpDG6HpW4U1pB8nQDxkAj1M4asDmdQclOe4FEJY agent
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/me/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/me/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/me/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/me/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/me/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:lKbkgpDG6HpW4U1pB8nQDxkAj1M4asDmdQclOe4FEJY agent
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/me/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/me/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/me/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/me/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

I tried deleting the github lines from `~/.ssh/known_hosts` and I tried deleting my key from my github settings, generating a new key, and uploading the new key as well.

I'm out of ideas. How can I resolve this authentication issue?

#### EDIT

Although the error occurs with and without the ssh config, here is my config file:

```
Host github
    User git
    HostName github.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github_id_rsa
Host foo
    HostName foo.example.com
Host *
    AddKeysToAgent yes
    User me
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    IdentitiesOnly yes
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the relevant parts of your `.ssh/config` file. In other words, show why you think ssh should be using the `~/.ssh/github_id_rsa` key to authenticate.

Comment: @Kenster I added my config, although this does not seem to be a config issue, since it fails without the config, too.

Comment: I think this may have been a case that's covered by [this SuperUser answer](https://superuser.com/a/436015/288643). Using `Host *` matches everything so **adds** the key specified by `IdentityFile` to a list of allowed keys that also contains the one added by `Host github`. The agent has both keys opened, sees that both are allowed for that host, and may try them in an unexpected order. Adding the keys to the agent in order of precedence may help, but you're better off specifying keys per host if you have any hosts that _must not_ use other keys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR Your config file "github" entry should look like this:

```
Host github.com   <--Note "github.com"
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github_id_rsa
```

Your immediate problem is that ssh isn't trying the "github_id_rsa" key, because your "Host github" config entry doesn't apply to a connection to "github.com".
Your "github" entry currently looks like this:

```
Host github
    User git
    HostName github.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github_id_rsa
```

This would only apply when you run something like "ssh git@github", specifically specifying the host as "github". It doesn't apply when when you specify the host as "github.com" on the command line.

If you want to leave your config file the way is, then you should run "ssh github" or "ssh git@github" instead of "...@github.com". If you specify the host as "github" on the command line, then it'll match the "github" section in your config file (and the config file will set the correct actual hostname of "github.com").

Comment: This was my problem, which is why it wasn't obvious why nothing else was working.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, in my case it was my agent that was serving the last key i added to it,
so i just killed the agent using the following command

```
eval "$(ssh-agent -k)"
```